# How to undo $\log$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

My teacher told me in order to undo $\log$ you have to base both sides with the same number of the existing $\log$, but I don’t really understand why 4 and the power which is $\log_4$ cancels each other out, someone please tell me the process of it, not just the formula which I already know.

[image]

Comment: Because $\log_4 64$ is a number such that when you raise $4$ to it give syou $64.$ Just imagine $\log_4 64$ as a big, unwieldy blob representing such number. Now you do a very sweet trick... You raise $4$ to that thing, and you still preserve the equation, provided you also change the RHS accordingly. Get it?

Comment: Why is this question getting downvoted, while at the same time there are a number of formal answers? If it is so terrible shouldn't it just be closed? Plus the person asking is new to the forum, and nobody downvoting is showing the courtesy to explain why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're basically asking simplification of  $$a^{\log_a b} \tag 1$$

So suppose $$\log_b a =c$$

By definition of log, we've $$\log_b a =c \implies a^c =b \tag2$$

Now using $(2)$ and  $(1)$, we get $$a^{\log_a b}=a^{(c)}\tag3 $$

Now using $(3)$ and $(2)$, finally we've $$a^{\log_a b} =b$$

Comment: I don’t see how (2) connects to (3)

Comment: @JaysenCong see my edit.

Comment: Still don’t see the connection

Comment: @JaysenCong if $x=y$ and $y=z$, then $x=z$. See LHS and RHS carefully.

Comment: How does (1) =b

Comment: @JaysenCong That's what I did in my while answer. Using (1)(2)(3) I am deducing that $$a^{\log_a b}=a^c=b$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that by definition

$$x=\log_a b \iff a^x=b$$

then

$$a^{\log_a b}=b$$

Comment: @JaysenCong It works by the definition of log function, $\log_a b$ is that number such that $a^{\log_a b}=b$

Answer (score 1):

$a^{\log_a b}=b$ and $\log_a {a^b}=b$, by the very definition...

These are *inverse*  functions...

Comment: @JaysenCong This is a definition.  There is nothing to prove.

Comment: @Jaysen Cong by definition,  $\log_a b$ is the number such that $a$ raised to that power is $b$...  It's kind of convoluted but it's by definition...

Answer (score 0):

I think your confusion is in the statement that the 4 and the $\log_4$ "cancel each other". That's not very precise but it's a simplification of what's really happening. Think of $4^a$ as starting at $a$ and taking four steps forward and $\log_4 a$ taking four steps back. Then $4^{\log_4 a}$ would just put you back at $a$. You can read this is "Take four to the power of the number that you need to raise 4 to in order to get $a$."

So in your example, $4^{\log_4 64}$ would be read "Take four to the power of the number that you need to raise 4 to in order to get 64." The number you need to raise 4 to in order to get 64 is 3, so take 4 raised to that power and you get $4^3 = 64$.